# htaccess stop auto redirecting to a unknown folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

**I am using htaccess to redirect my URL and to hide .PHP extension but it take to a unknown folder following code i have used**

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]
```

When it redirect it shows following error

```
    Not Found
    The requested URL /abc/index was not found on this server.
    Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

my site name is like abc.com but it shows above error with unknown folder /abc/index

Comment: Line 3 and 4 of your .htaccess do this - you take www.(something) and redirect to www.abc/(something) - the $1 means that it inserts the content of the first parenthesis in the line above. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: these rules don't do what you want and only handle two things , force www  and add a php extension to index when it comes as it is, let us know what you want to do and paste the rest of rules

Comment: i want my site to redirect to www and its redirecting but I dont to show any folder (currently it shows my site name as folder) could you get me a example code